# Showing a visualization with Parent Child/Successor Predecessor relationship

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, visualization

I wanted suggestions from the community as to which chart should be used to depict the Parent-Child/Successor-Predecessor relationship in Power BI. I'm using Azure boards as a data source. Here is my sample data source.

[image]

I want to show each work item id in the center and its Predecessor on the top left and successor on the bottom right. With that, I want to arrange my items based on iteration.

Here is how I'm trying to visualize my data.

[image]

I don't need links to the Microsoft Custom Visuals Page. I know that it exists. I'm expecting somebody to point out to a visual in the market place that could help me with my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there any exact option for data presentation as per your design/requirement or not. But to serve the purpose, you can try with "**Multi-row card**" and the presentation will be something like below-

[image]

You can apply some Styling in the visual, but it will not like your sample requirement I guess :(

> Here 2 column is basically 2 different "Multi-row card" visual.

> In first visual, applied filter with Iteration = 1

> In second visual, applied filter with Iteration = 2

> For better presentation purpose, I replaced NULL value with a "-" in column "Predecessos ID" & "Source ID Title"